# Batch file to copy files to auto generated folder based on auto generated folder name

Tags: batch-file, if-statement, xcopy

I'm publishing content to autogenerated folders and after the publishing has finished I want to copy files to that folder based on the foldersname using a batch

The autogenerated folders always have a language name, for example German, Dutch, French and English.

What I want my batch to do is that when the folder name is German it copies all the files from C:\Sourcefolder\DE\ to the new generated folder I'm running the batch from. I've tried to find something myself but my lack of knowledge results in this:

```
CHDIR /D %1

@ECHO OFF 
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=%cd%"

IF "%1"=="German" goto :German

:German
xcopy /Y "C:\Sourcefolder\DE\*.jpg" "%1"

GOTO :EOF
```

Is there anyone who can help me in the right direction?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Which string is passed as parameter to the batch file, just __German__, __English__, __Greek__, etc. or something longer like an entire path ending with a language name?

Comment: @Mofi just German, English, Greek etc. not the entire path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code for a batch file which might do what you want.

```
@echo off
rem Is this batch file called without any parameter?
if "%~1"=="" (
    echo.
    echo Run %~nx0 with language as first parameter.
    echo.
    echo Example: %~nx0 English
    echo.
    pause
    goto :EOF
)

if /I "%~1"=="German"  set "ShortName=DE" & goto CopyFiles
if /I "%~1"=="English" set "ShortName=EN" & goto CopyFiles

rem This batch file was called with a (language) string not listed above.
echo.
echo Error: "%~1" is not a supported language.
echo.
pause
goto :EOF

:CopyFiles
rem Copy all JPEG files of the specified language from source folder
rem to the specified language folder in current working directory.
xcopy /H /I /K /Q /R /Y "C:\SourceFolder\%ShortName%\*.jpg" "%~1"
set "ShortName="
```

Some notes additionally to the comments in the batch code:

`%~1` is replaced by `cmd.exe` on execution of the batch file with the string of first parameter with removing double quotes if batch file was called for example with `"English"` instead of just `English` as first parameter.

If you want to know more about `%~1` or `%~nx0` (name of batch file with extension but without drive and path), open a command prompt window, run there `call /?` and read help output for this command.

`/I` option of command `if` makes the string comparison case-insensitive.

The ampersand in `set "ShortName=DE" & goto CopyFiles` concatenates the two commands `set` and `goto` on a single line which makes it possible here to specify 2 commands for each `if` without using parentheses. See [Conditional Execution](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-conditional.html) for details about this special operator.

For details on the switches used on command `xcopy` run in a command prompt window `xcopy /?` and read output help.

By the way: The batch files copies the JPEG files into specified language subfolder of **current working directory**. The current working directory can be the directory the batch file is stored, but can be also a different directory depending on how batch file was started and from which directory. If you want to make sure that the JPEG files are copied into specified language subfolder of **batch file directory**, you would need for the line with `xcopy`:

```
xcopy /H /I /K /Q /R /Y "C:\SourceFolder\%ShortName%\*.jpg" "%~dp0%~1"
```